# Cannot login to jBPM5.4 console

Tags: jbpm

I have migrated database from default H2 to MySQL by following the tutorial (https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SetUpJBPM54FinalInstallerToUseMySQL-OrHowToRunSection37OfTheUserGuide). Now when i start the jBPM (by **ant start.demo.db**), tables are getting created in jbpm5 database.

My problem is when i am trying to login to jbpm-console, it shows "authentication failed" error, when i checked server log it shows below error.

"Failed to load users/passwords/role files: java.io.IOException: No properties file: users.properties or defaults: defaultUsers.properties".

I already copied jbpm-installer/auth/roles.properties and jbpm-installer/auth/users.properties to jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration folder. Still the same error shows...

Please give me some suggestion ...

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates it cannot find the users.properties file though.  So I suggest you double-check the security domain is configured correctly and the files are where they should be:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/5.4.0.Final/jbpm-installer/standalone.xml#L279

Kris